# Is Socratic badge broken?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I had `87/100` progress on [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) several days ago. After that I had at least 3 days with new question with positive score. But the progress is still `87/100`.

Is it broken?

**UPD:** on the "Recently Deleted Questions" page I have only 1 question, which was deleted  10 days ago.

Comment: If you posted two questions on the same day only one of them counts. If a question gets deleted, I imagine that also affects the score. Can you confirm that all 90 questions were posted on separate days and none were deleted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah. You can check my previous 3 questions. Asked on separate days. No one of them was counted.

Comment: Yes, that may be true for the last three questions but what about questions that may have been deleted in the last week without you knowing? Eliminate as many possible scenarios and, for me, you have a bug. I don't know why a user removed that  tag and replaced it with support but that user knows more about SE than I do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think, the chance that during this 3 days 3 of my old questions were deleted is really small. For me it looks like a bug.

Comment: @rene on the "Recently Deleted Questions" page I have only 1 question, which was deleted  10 days ago.

Comment: @rene no, [it was about Question Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344627/add-string-from-the-new-wizard-into-transifex). And it was deleted by myself.

Comment: @rene there were at least 4 posts ([one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344967/260198), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345031/260198), [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344967/260198), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345101/260198)), that met criteria but weren't counted.

Comment: Let's assume for now the badge job didn't run [as your progress is 91](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/919952/socratic-badge-progress?userid=260198). I'm sure this will rectify its self in 6 to 8 days, way before you actually are eligible for the badge.